# How can I let the IBM Jazz 'Check-in and Deliver' wizard immediately show my default work item?

Tags: jazz

In Eclipse, using IBM Jazz for source control, I have a default task with state 'In Progress', that's assigned to me.

In the 'Check-in and Deliver' wizard, in the 2nd wizard-pane ('Associate Work Item') sometimes this task is displayed immediately, and other times it is not. In the latter case it only appears when I type a matching search criterium

How can I make sure that my default task appears in this 2nd wizard-pane immediately, without the need to type a search criterium?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a defect - and worth raising on jazz.net. Be sure to specify what version of RTC you are using.

However, there is an easier way to do what you want.  At any point you can drag the work item to the bottom line of the Eclipse UI (you may see "no work item" or similar text in the area you need to drag the work item.  This then becomes the default work item your code is associated with.  You will no longer have to use the Associate work item.

Foe example, in RTC v4.0.1 - this part of the help explains this idea in more detail:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0m1/topic/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_scm_eclipse_workitems_working.html

This function has been part of RTC since v1 so will work regardless of what version you are using.

Hope that helps

Comment: I am already using the functionality you mention, but it requires me to deliver each change set in 4 steps: check in, wait until it has finished checking in, type my check-in comments, deliver. I was hoping that the 'Check-in and Deliver' wizard reduces that number of steps, which it does when it preselects my default task. But it does not always preselect it, and I wonder how to force it to preselect it.